# Implementing logical nested select in quickForm SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, quickform

```
Property.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  'LGA': {
    label: "L.G.A",
    type: String,
    allowedValues:
    ["Aba","Oha", "Enu"],
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
          firstOption: "(Pls, Select the L.G.A)"
        }
    }
  }
,
'Town': {
  label: "Town",
  type: String,
  allowedValues:
  ["Abakpa","Ewula", "Ezeoka", "Ubu","Echa", "Onu" ,"Eke", "Afor"],
  autoform: {
    afFieldInput: {
      firstOption: "(Pls, Select the Ward)"
    }
    }
  }

});
```

I have the schema above and I am using quickForm to implement this schema. "Abakpa","Ewula", "Ezeoka" are towns in "Aba" LGA while "Ubu","Echa", "Onu" are towns in "Oha" LGA and "Eke", "Afor" belong to "Enu" LGA. This is just for illustration because the list is quite numerous. I want a situation where if "Aba" is selected, the option that will be available for the Town select field would be "Abakpa","Ewula", "Ezeoka". If Oha is selected then "Ubu","Echa", "Onu" will be the next option in the Town schema etc. Pls, how do I implement this?.Thanks.

Comment: i'm afraid that you won't be able to do that using only `autoform` you need to do it in the template manually using helpers.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, any suggestion on what the template helper should look like. Thanks.

Comment: well there's a quite of tasks to do. ping me at `faysal@yahoo.com`, i'll try to help you.